# How to create index and type in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have installed elasticsearch version `2.3.2`. I have to add `index` and `type` to that elasticsearch. Before I used sense plugin to achieve this. But the addon was removed from webstore. Please give suggestion.

Answer (score 9):

Sense plugin is now a Kibana app. Please refer [official reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/sense/current/installing.html) for installation.

The answer of your question is, you can create index and type in Elasticsearch by running below curl command

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/IndexName/TypeName"
```

Comment: You have to run this command from command line. In which OS you are trying this ?

Comment: if i run means getting 'curl' is not a recognized command error .

Comment: You have to install curl first .

Answer (score 6):

All operations in Elasticsearch can be done via REST API calls.

To create an index use the `index API`

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/twitter?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"settings" : {"index" : {"number_of_shards" : 3, "number_of_replicas" : 0 }}}'
```

To create the mapping the you can use the `_mapping` endpoint-

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweets/_mapping -d @"create_p4_schema_payload.json"
```

Here,mapping is provided via a json file name `create_p4_schema_payload.json` which contains the following-

```
{
  "properties": {
    "user_name": {
      "type": "text"
    }
  }
}
```

All these can be run via any terminal which supports curl. For windows, you may install `cygwin` to run linux command from command prompt.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a Rest client like postman to do this. You can get the postman as a chrome extension.

The other way is to do an SSH into one of the nodes in your cluster and run the POST command using CURL.

```
`curl -X POST 'localhost:9200/bookindex/books' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
 {
    "bookId" : "A00-3",
    "author" : "Sankaran",
    "publisher" : "Mcgrahill",
    "name" : "how to get a job"
 }'
```

I will automatically create an index named 'bookindex' with type 'books' and index the data. If index and type already exist it will add the entry to the index.

Answer (score 1):

Like it was said above, you can access it through REST api calls. The command you need to run is:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/IndexName?include_type_name=TypeName'
```

CURL is a raw text that can be imported into Postman, for example, or you can install it's CLI and simply run it. Simply put:

It's a PUT api call to the ElasticSearch/IndexName, adding the Query Parameter include_type_name.

The reference guide is at: [Elastic Search - Create index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sense plugin is removed from chrome webstore. You could use Kibana which has sense like dev-tool to perform ElasticSearch queries.

> Follow [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/deb.html) link to install kibana.